# wsl2 docker mysql not listening on port 3306

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker

i'm trying to setup a local enviroment with laravel-sail on wsl2 (debian).
I followed the laravel sail guide and everything works well except I can't connect to mysql in the docker container from the host.

docker ps
[image: ![enter image description here]

sudo ss -tulpn
[image]

Why mysql doesn't listen to 3306 port?

Comment: Is MySQL started?

Comment: yes, i can connect to it using wsl2 but i can't using heidisql from windows

Comment: try to connect using ssh, maybe your mysql can not access by remote ip